# Call Javascript from Objective-C through Cordova plugin

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm working on an iPad app project that is using Phonegap (cordova 2.0.0).

I know how to write a plugin so I can call a native method from the javascript, but what I really need now is to be able to call a Javascript method from my native code through a plugin. Something like:

```
- (void) callTestJsFunction
{
    [super writeJavascript:@"testJsFunction();"];
}
```

that would call a `testJsFunction()` located in one of my JS files in the `www` folder. We're using Sencha Touch that handles some logic and I need to call a function from the `app.js`.

I couldn't find any example of this kind on the web, so first I wonder if it is possible to do such a thing? and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a plugin and put the native code there instead using it in the AppDelegate.m.

From the plugin class you can do this:

`NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJSFunction(\"%@\");", stringParameter];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];`

[Phonegap Cordova call javascript functions from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748631/phonegap-cordova-call-javascript-functions-from-objective-c)