# Phonegap Cordova call javascript functions from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I am facing some Objective-C lackiness of knowledge in my PhoneGap App.

I have a library that I need to implement in Objective-C. This Library has some callbacks that I receive in a delegate Class ( called CCController ) :

```
[MyLib sharedInstance].delegate = self;
```

This Class is instanciated in the AppDelegate.m like this :

```
CCController *myClass = [CCController alloc];
[myClass init];
```

Then, when my Lib sends events, the functions in my CCController are called.
I need, at this point, to call my Javascript functions with a parameter.

How can I implement this ?

I have tried calling a function in AppDelegate.m which contains this :

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJSFunction(\"%@\");", stringParameter];
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

But without success, nothing is called in my JS...

How can I implement this ? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create a plugin and put the native code there instead using it in the `AppDelegate.m`.

From the plugin class you can do this:

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJSFunction(\"%@\");", stringParameter];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

[Plugin development guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this and it is not mentionned in the documentation.

Now I want to know what is the best way to call functions in my Plugin Class from my CCController ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, js functions? Or native functions

Comment: The native code in my CCController class have to call natives functions in my Plugin class, so that I have access to the webView to call my javascript functions then.

Comment: If you tell me the library you are using I can take a look, but you can just use [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString]; whenever you want to call a js funcion

Comment: I want to call a function into the plugin from another Objective-C class. How can I do this (thanks for help)

Comment: The other class have to call a plugin class function that contains the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString function. It can be with a delegate, a notification or any other native way